# Combine 2 arrays values

Tags: php

I need to combine 2 arrays like this:

```
$a = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$b = array('1', '2', '3');
```

And obtain this result:
A1
A2
A3
B1
B2
B3
C1
C2
C3
D1
D2
D3
E1
E2
E3

Can anyone help?

Thanls!@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `foreach` you can loop into these array to obtain their value:

```
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!

$a = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$b = array('1', '2', '3');
              
foreach( $a as $A_value ){
    foreach( $b as $B_value ){
        echo $A_value . $B_value . ' ';
    }
}
// the output A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 C1 C2 C3 D1 D2 D3 E1 E2 E3
```